# Recurring MOD_SECURITY upon logging into the site admin page

Tags: security

My website has migrated from one hosting server to another. Since then, for the reason I am unsure about, when I try to log into my admin page the following error occurs.

[image: Error message]

After getting stuck with it for a while I have found the following:

1. This error only happens on my desktop with my ISP service.
2. I can still access the admin page via my phone and actually never had the problem.
3. When I connect to my home ISP Wifi on my phone when, I get the same problem.
4. When I have my desktop connected to my phone mobile hotspot, I can log into the admin page.
5. My ISP suggested that I restart my router to change my IP address, which actually gives me access to the admin page, but in about 15 minutes, the same error occurs and I can never log into the admin site after this.
6. Clearing browser history does not work either.

I have checked with my both my server host and ISP tech support parties and they are both pointing at one another and claiming that they have not blocked this domain.

Joomla experts, how do I get around this issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was the server host in the end. 
Whew.. I spent a lot of time going back and forth. But I learned a lot through this and will definitely deal with such issue better next time :)

Answer (score 1):

You're lucky that your website told you that the error is generated by ModSecurity, which must have helped you a lot in addressing the problem. Addressing any ModSecurity issue either consists of 1) Addressing the code triggering the ModSecurity rule, or 2) Whitelisting the ModSecurity rule.

Note that you can whitelist a ModSecurity rule in a specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps (as a troubleshooting step at least) to disable mod_security.

With many hosts, this can be done by adding the following code to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928404/1983389 for more details.