# Occasional 403 errors when saving articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, server, permissions, server-configuration

I have a strange error in Joomla backend. I get a forbidden error when trying to save article from certain custom component in Joomla it doesn't happen for all articles which baffles me a lot.

I get a:

> You don't have permission to access /administrator/index.php on this
>   server.

I had installed sourcerer and suspected it was causing the problem but sadly that didnt seem to be the problem.

Any thoughts guys?

**Update**
It seems when I insert a link into my article using the editor is when I get this error. I guess it might be a security related issue.

Comment: what file security is this, i am on windows IIS hosting, where and how to change the security for which file?

Comment: [@webmaster](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/13061/webmaster) would like to know: "_What file security is this, I am on windows IIS hosting, where and how to change the security for which file?_"

Comment: mod security is an apache module not windows iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost 100% positive that this is ModSecurity. Check the ModSecurity log on your server and try whitelisting the rule that is being triggered. If you can't do that (possibly because you are on a shared host), then ask your host to do that for you, if they won't, then move to a VPS with root access and do it yourself.

Comment: You may be able to disable mod_security at least temporarily to narrow down the problem. For details see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23952/120

Answer (score 2):

A **403 error** denotes that **the operation/task is not permitted**. This is usually comes from **strict permissions**, or **security settings** posed by the server e.g. a firewall, or it can be due to **file permissions**.

From your updated information, my guess is that the 403 error you are encountering comes from a **software firewall** - it could a Joomla extension like the **WAF** of **Admin Tools Pro**, or it can be a WAF on the server level (**`mod_security`**).

You need to go through and investigate your logs in order to get a clue. If you don't manage your server, then report this to your hosting provider as well and seek for help. They should be able to give you more information and even fix it for you, by whitelisting the operation that get's blocked (if it comes from a server WAF or it's another server configuration related issue).